# Excel Data Manipulation - One Row into Multiple Rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to format data so that I can import it into a system.  I have the data sitting in 1 row that stretches across ~1200 columns.

The row contains the ID in bold, then the roles associated with the ID.  I need to write a formula/macro that pushes each ID onto a new row line.

Current: 
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbMSv.png)

What I want:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79TZ4.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro to start automating the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would do it. It ignores bold/normal, but uses the identifier of the key being purely a numeric value rather than a number/word combo..?

```
Dim col As Long, rw As Long

col = 1
rw = 2

With ActiveSheet.Rows(1)
    Do Until .Cells(col) = ""
        If IsNumeric(.Cells(col).Value) Then
            rw = rw + 1
            Cells(rw, 1) = .Cells(col).Value
        Else
            Cells(rw, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1) = .Cells(col).Value
        End If
        col = col + 1
    Loop
End With
```